# PHP mail() function

Tags: php, phpmailer, compiler-warnings, ini

I use the PHP `mail()` function in a program to send email. This is the code:

```
<?php

ini_set ('SMTP', 'my.domain');
mail ("email@gmail.com", "PHP mail function", "Body of email", "From:emailer@gmail.com");

?>
```

I get this error:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
>   25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
>   ini_set() in C:\mail.php on line 41

I have made sure the *SMTP* and *smtp_port* setting in *php.ini* are set:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the smtp server in your php.ini file.

Comment: Take a look at `phpinfo()` to ensure your SMTP settings are actually what you think they are.  Sometimes you edit PHP.ini and due to a syntax error or unprintable character, your settings don't load.  Or, you edited the wrong file.

Comment: Sounds like your server doesn't have an SMTP service running, which is not at all surprising for a Windows machine (evidenced by the `C:\mail.php`). You need to setup access to an SMTP service, probably a 3rd party one (like login and send with Gmail). It is _very highly_ recommended not to use `mail()` and instead use a class like PHPMailer. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: Dozens of things can go wrong when trying to send mail, the first of which is not having an SMTP service available to send through. Using PHPMailer will help solve at least a large number of those dozens of things. The rest are wrapped in DNS settings, spam filters, careful header construction, etc. It's a minefield.

Comment: Also make sure you restart your services after editing config files.

Comment: @Daenarys  How do I configure smtp server in the php.ini file?  In my question I have a section of the php.ini file with SMTP configurations.  Is that it?

Comment: For your own sanity, **please** use something like http://swiftmailer.org/ instead of the raw `mail` command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure SMTP is running on the machine. Either that or point your application to another SMTP host.

Comment: I installed PHPmailer.  Am I missing something from my PHP code activating PHPmailer to use smtp?  I have done the PHPmailer tutorial from woxware.com

Comment: @Fuel so you have `PHPmailer` why are you still using `mail()`

Comment: @meda  I want to use mail().  It is simpler than the phpmailer tutorial.

Comment: @Fuel no it is not simpler, hence your question

Comment: @meda How so?  I mail() with its parameters is only one line of php code where phpmailer tutorial has many lines of code.

Comment: @Fuel `mail` is deceptively simple. You'll find that a simple `mail` call will get caught by most spam filters unless you do some work to set a variety of headers. Sending HTML email or attachments is a **nightmare**. Use something like PHPMailer or http://swiftmailer.org/ for your own sanity.

Comment: `mail()` requires that you are running a local mail server. Otherwise you need to use something that will talk SMTP directly, like PHPMailer. Either way, building your own messages is really not recommended as it's very hard to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you're running windows, install fakesendmail 
http://glob.com.au/sendmail/

If you're on *NIX install sendmail
 on Linux
  issue > `yum install sendmail`          //Fedora, Centos
  issue > `apt-get install sendmail`      //Debian, Ubuntu

Once you've done that, sending mail and using the mail function in php shouldn't be an issue. 

In addition, you can check your maillog, which is extremely useful 

 issue> `tailf /var/log/maillog`

you may need `sudo` permission if you don't have root privileges on linux or unix
```

Comment: Don't install sendmail. It's what most decent mail servers emulate as far as calling a local sendmail binary go, but sendmail itself is slow and inefficient compared with just about everything else - most Linux distros default to postfix or exim, eitehr of which are easier to deal with than sendmail.

Comment: Sendmail is an old habbit. I also like how exim dispatches mail. I used it in the past, never had any performance issue on Debian 6.